# Edit property of all elements in a database table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rake, rails-activerecord, rails-migrations

I have a database with 30 - 50 users and I'd like to edit a property in everyone of them.

I'm not well versed in the arts of SQL but I think a for or some sort of loop would work.

Instead of having to write :

```
u = User.find(id)
u.air = true
u.save
```

What could I write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want them to all be updated in the same way, try:

```
User.update_all(air: true)
```

If you require different updates for each, try:

```
User.all.each do |u|
    u.air = true
    # add whatever other logic you need here
    u.save
end
```

Comment: Thank you ! Just what I needed.